# ¿Cómo hacer que seleccione el dato esta función PHP?

Tags: php

Hola gente quiero saber porque no me Funciona este codigo quiero hacer que selecione un idioma pero en lugar de eso seleciona el primer archivo en la carpeta 
bueno aqui dejo el codigo fuente y un ejemplo:

```
<?php

function displayLangSelect($lang)
{

    $languages_dir = "languages";
    $lang_found = 0;

    if (is_dir($languages_dir)) {

        if ($dh = opendir($languages_dir)) {

            $i = 0;
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {

                if (substr($file,-1) != "." && pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == "php") {

                    $i++;

                    $file_name = $file;

                    // Open file to get language name
                    include($languages_dir . "/" . $file_name);

                    $lang_found = 1;

                    // Strip extension
                    //$file_name = preg_replace("/\..*$/", "", $file_name);

                        $line = "<option value=".$Languages_option."";
                    if ($file_name == $lang)
                        $line .= " selected";
                        $line .= ">";
                        $line .= $Languages_select;
                        $line .= "</option>";

                    $langsAr[] = $line;

                    include($languages_dir . "/" . $lang .".php");

                }
            }
            closedir($dh);

            if ($lang_found == 0) {

                echo "Error: <strong>languages</strong> folder empty!";

            } else {

                if ($i > 1) {

                    sort($langsAr);

                    echo  " ";
                    echo "<select class=\"input__settings\" name=\"language\" id=\"language\">";
                    foreach ($langsAr AS $lang) {
                        echo $lang;
                    }
                    echo "</select>";

                } else {
                    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"lang\" value=\"" . $file_name . "\">";
                }
            }

        } else {

            echo "Error: <strong>languages</strong> folder locked!";
        }

    } else {
        echo "Error: <strong>languages</strong> folder missing!";
    }
}






?>


<?php
        $ex = "es";

        echo ''.displayLangSelect($ex).'';
?>
```

Ejemplo **es.php** :

```
$Languages_select = 'Español';
$Languages_option = 'es';
```

Ejemplo **en.php** :

```
$Languages_select = 'English';
$Languages_option = 'en';
```

Ejemplo **fr.php** :

```
$Languages_select = 'français';
$Languages_option = 'en';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acabo de probarlo y se arregla descomentando esta línea:

```
//$file_name = preg_replace("/\..*$/", "", $file_name);
```

Al estar comentada, el valor de `$file_name` es el nombre completo del archivo, con la extensión incluida, y entonces este `if` no se cumple nunca porque las comparaciones quedan como `es.php == es`, `fr.php == fr`, etc:

```
if ($file_name == $lang)
  $line .= " selected";
```

Comment: si tienes razon se me paso por alto eso Gracias